# Cómo puedo comparar un valor de un QuerySnapshot con un valor local Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Tengo un valor de un query que viene de un stream QuerySnapshot, quisiera recorrer esos datos e ir poniendolos en pantalla.

Estoy creando un CARD que muestra los dias de una semana, y quiero que en esos dias de la semana se muestre los valores que existan en el query.

Este es el codigo que tengo ahora.

```dart
return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          SliverAppBar(
            pinned: true,
            floating: true,
            expandedHeight: 200.0,
            title: AppAbar(),
            flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
              background: FlexibleAppBar(),
            ),
            leading: Icon(Icons.menu, color: Colors.white, size: 30.0,),
          ),
          SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
                List.generate(6, (idx) {
                  return Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                    child: Card(
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0)),
                      elevation: 3,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                      child: Consumer<TimeSheetRepository>(
                              builder: (BuildContext context, TimeSheetRepository db, Widget child) {
                                _queryWeekYear = db.queryByMonthYear(
                                    12, 2020);
                                return StreamBuilder(
                                    stream: _queryWeekYear,
                                    builder: (context, snapshot){
                                      if(!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data.documents == null) return CircularProgressIndicator();
                                      return ListTile(
                                        leading: Column(
                                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                          children: [
                                            Text('${_numWeeks[idx]}'),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                        title: Container(
                                          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/16,
                                          child: ListView.builder(
                                              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                              shrinkWrap: true,
                                              itemCount: 7,
                                              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                                return Padding(
                                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
                                                  child: Column(
                                                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                                      children: [
                                                        Row(
                                                          children: [
                                                            Column(
                                                              children: [
                                                                Text('${(DateFormat('EEEE').format(firstweek[index]).substring(0, 1))}',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0, color: Colors.black54)),
                                                              ],
                                                            ),
                                                            SizedBox(width: 28.0),
                                                          ],
                                                        ),
                                                      ]
                                                  ),
                                                );
                                              }
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        subtitle: Container(
                                          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/20,
                                          child: ListView.builder(
                                              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                              shrinkWrap: true,
                                              itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                                              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                                DocumentSnapshot docSnapshot = snapshot.data.documents[index];
                                                return Column(
                                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                                    children: [
                                                      Row(
                                                        children: [
                                                          Column(
                                                            children: [
                                                              Text('${docSnapshot['date'].toString()}',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0, color: Colors.black54)),
                                                              **// Aqui es donde estoy tratando de encontrar el valor en mi QuerySnashot y colocarlo en el Widget que le asigne la fecha correspondiente**
                                                            ],
                                                          ),
                                                          SizedBox(width: 28.0),
                                                        ],
                                                      ),
                                                    ]
                                                );
                                              }
                                          )
                                        ),
                                        trailing: Column(
                                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                          children: [
                                            Container(
                                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorLight.withOpacity(0.2),
                                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                                              ),
                                              child: Padding(
                                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                                child: Text( "148", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue.shade800, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 18.0),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      );
                                }
                                );
                              }
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                })
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Cabe destacar que los dias que hay en el QuerySnapshot no necesariamente estan todos. Es decir, Quiero crear un Card que va acontener los dias de una semana en especifico y debajo de cada dia quiero poner el valor que esta en mi Query. Por ende no necesariamente existiran todos los dias de la semana. Pero quiero mostrar la semana completa con los valores que existen

Estoy agregando una imagen de ejemplo. Ahi se ve 5 Crads que representan las semanas, estas semanas tienen a su vez los dias como TITLE (encerrado en el cuadro azul), en el SUBTITLE es en donde quiero mostrar los datos que tengo en mi bd.

Como se ve en la imagen, estoy mostrando valores para los dias Lunes y Martes (encerrado en el cuadro rojo) pero el resto de los dias no necesariamente. Vale destacar que los dias de la semana mostrados en letras, tienen su valor como tal, o sea, el lunes de la semana 50 su valor es 7-Dic-2020 y solo muestro la primera letra correspondiente.

Comment: Hola bienvenido a StackOverflow en español, las preguntas del tipo: "quiero realiza esto", sin proporcionar información de lo que ya se ha intentado o el error que se esta recibiendo, suelen ser mal aceptadas, por favor edita tu pregunta. Revisa [ask].

Comment: Tengo el Stream QuerySnapshot y no sé cómo ir recorriendo los valores del query he ir tomando esos valores.

Comment: Podrías por favor agregar el código que has intentando o tienes realizado, junto con el error que recibes o problema, para poder replicar mejor lo que estas intentando.

Comment: No veo donde intentas utilizar `QuerySnapshot` en que parte del código estas teniendo problemas o que error te sale ?

Comment: Utilizo un query que es este _queryWeekYear el cual por medio de un Stream me traigo el QuerySnapshot

Comment: ok, por lo que entiendo sería que intentas mostrar lo que vendría de `snapshot.data.daysWeek`  por poner un ejemplo, por que ya muestras dentro de `Card` en un `ListView.builder` lo que viene de `snapshot.data.documents`.

Comment: Explico un poco. En un Card creo los días de una semana con un Listview.builder luego quiero mostrar los días que tengo en mi bd (que no siempre serán todos los de la semana) dentro del día correspondiente. Es decir, si tengo mi Lunes como el día 1 hasta el domingo 7 pero en mi bd solo tengo el día 2, 4 y 5. Quiero mostrar lo que tengo en esos días en el widget del día ya creado

Comment: Puedes mostrar el `Widget` donde quieres mostrarlos?. Por que lo que mencionas sería otro `Stream` o `Future` para mostrarlos utilizando la consulta correspondiente para solo obtener los días que están en tu `bd`.

Comment: En el title estoy creando los 7 días de la semana, en el subtitle es donde quiero mostrar los días que pudiera tener en la bd.

Comment: Por lo que veo en tu código en el `subtitle` estas mostrando lo que viene en `snapshot.data.documents[index]`  dentro de un `ListView.builder` por lo que entiendo deben ser los días que quieres mostrar. No entiendo del todo que error estar recibiendo o si es que quieres mostrar en conjunto los días con la lista que ya se muestra.

Comment: Correcto Richard. Imagina esto: Un Card que muestra los dias de la semana de un mes en especifico. Ese Card lo hago manualmente con su valores reales. Como si fuera un calendario con cosas que hacer, quiero mostrar en algunos dias los valores que se van incluyendo en mi bd. Lo que no se es como puedo match los datos que ya tengo en la Card con lo que tengo en la bd. Pues en mi card va a existir el dia mas no necesariamente ese dia tengo algo que mostrar.

Comment: Tendrías algún ejemplo del como quieres el resultado?, ya que al ejecutar tu código queda un poco confuso ya que el espacio asignado es demasiado corto para las listas, probablemente sea mejor fuera de un `ListTile`

Comment: Listo Richard, ya agregue la imagen como ejemplo. Si hay alguna duda avisame y explico un poco mejor. Gracias